# Displaying a DIV on top of a Textarea element

Tags: html, textarea, css-position

I have a small "floating_Note_DIV" which I want to display on top of a textarea, as shown in the pictures. As well, I want to show a yellow_DIV below the textarea, flushed with the bottom edge of the textarea. If I do not display the floating_Note_DIV, the textarea is flushed with yellow_DIV (seen below in Image_1).
[image: Image_1 Without f_N_DIV]

However, if I display the floating_Note_DIV, a gap appears between the textarea and the yellow_DIV ; i.e.,  I was thinking that if I put position: relative, and top and left/right I would get the f_N_DIV to fly over the textarea. It does seem to work however it looks like a gap is left where the "footprint" of the f_N_Div is left behind, at it's "supposed-to-be" position between tomato_DIV and yellow_DIV (see below Image_2).
[image: Image_2 With f_N_DIV]

If I use position "Absolute" it gets positioned w.r.t to the whole page, I am expecting the tomato_DIV to move around and so the f_N_DIV will have to be positioned w.r.t the textarea or tomato_DIV.
Any workaround? Thanks, all help appreciated ! !

the HTML is:

```
<div id='tomato_DIV' >   
        <textarea  id="textarea_main" cols="40" rows="3" maxlength="300"></textarea>
    
        <div id="floating_Note_DIV">Your Thoughts!!</div>       
    
        <div id="yellow_DIV"></div>
</div>
```

the relavant CSS is:

```
#tomato_DIV
{   background-color: tomato;
    padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
    width: 310px;   
    border-radius: 5px; }   
#textarea_main
{   box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 5px 5px 0px 5px; padding: 2px;      /*  note: bottom margin is 0 to make flush with yellow div */
    width: calc(100% - 10px); 
    height: 75px; 
    resize: none; outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #737d96;   border-radius: 3px;    }   
#floating_Note_DIV
{   margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; 
    padding: 0px 2px 0px 0px;
    
    position: relative;                 /* how to do this bit? */
    right: -232px;  
    top: -14px;
            
    width: 70px;    
    height: 11px;
            
    font-size: 8px; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold;  color: black;
    text-align: right;  border: 1px solid #737d96;  }
#yellow_DIV
{   margin: 0px 5px 5px 5px;            /*  note: top margin is 0 to make flush with textarea */
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: calc(100% -10px);
    height: 30px;   background-color: #fdffb6;    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

**HTML :** Put the `#floating_Note_DIV` element inside `#yellow_DIV`. You could leave it where it is, but setting `top` CSS property would have been difficult.

**CSS :**

1. Change `position` property of `#floating_Note_DIV` from `relative` to `absolute`.
2. Set `position` property of `#yellow_DIV` to `relative`.
3. Set `right` to `0`.
4. Set `bottom` to `100%`.
5. I modified the `margin-bottom` to `5px` to align it perfectly.

```css
#tomato_DIV {
  background-color: tomato;
  padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
  width: 310px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#textarea_main {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 5px 5px 0px 5px;
  padding: 2px;
  /*  note: bottom margin is 0 to make flush with yellow div */
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  height: 75px;
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #737d96;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#floating_Note_DIV {
  margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
  padding: 0px 2px 0px 0px;
  position: relative;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 100%;
  width: 70px;
  height: 11px;
  font-size: 8px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  text-align: right;
  border: 1px solid #737d96;
}

#yellow_DIV {
  margin: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
  /*  note: top margin is 0 to make flush with textarea */
  border: 1px solid grey;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: calc(100% -10px);
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #fdffb6;
}
```

```html
<div id='tomato_DIV'>
  <textarea id="textarea_main" cols="40" rows="3" maxlength="300">
  </textarea>

  <div id="yellow_DIV">
    <div id="floating_Note_DIV">Your Thoughts!!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it does work! Even when I added additional P elements inside the yellow_DIV, the F_N_Div stays at the bottom right of the textarea. But what I dont understand, is two things: i) When I tried position absolute, it was positioning the f_N_DIV 'absolutely' with respect to entire browser window, how did you lock it to Yellow, also ii) the bottom is 100% , what is this referring to.. bottom edge of f_N_D with... if you could explain, that would be great! or point me to somewhere I can read.. thank you so much Pranav!

Comment: I am sorry for not explaining while posting. For your first question, the answer is, I positioned the parent `#yellow_DIV` as `relative`. I forgot to mention that as well while posting. Reason is because the absolute positioned element is positioned according the closest positioned ancestor. Earlier, no ancestor element was positioned. That is why, it got positioned with respect to browser window. For second question, the explanation is that the element is moved according to bottom edge, and 100% is equal to the height of `#yellow_DIV`. You'd have to google stuff, for better understanding.

Comment: Wow Pranav, thanks so much!! I never knew that the parent div has to be positioned, and about ancestral positioning cascading down to element. Makes it cleare, and learnt something new. I will figure out the 100%.. thanks so much again mate.. cheers!!

Comment: Your welcome. Don't forget to mark the answer as correct. Cheers!